# LESS comment on top of file, before import

Tags: less

**foo.css**

```
.foo {
  //...
}
```

**bar.less**

```
/*
 * Some comment
 */

@import (inline) "foo.css";
```

LESS compiles this to **bar.css**

```
.foo {
  //...
}

/*
 * Some comment
 */
```

How do I get the correct order?

```
/*
 * Some comment
 */

.foo {
  //...
}
```

Comment: What compiler it is? The reference one generates [the expected result](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%2F*%5Cn%20*%20Some%20comment%5Cn%20*%2F%5Cn%5Cn%40import%20(inline)%20%5C%22https%3A%2F%2Fgist.githubusercontent.com%2Fseven-phases-max%2F974c283f506b3fd991a086678ce72034%2Fraw%2F87ea6ee8056ab28ee7c6676aec73eb66ad9ba0d9%2Fsome.css%5C%22%3B%5Cn%22%7D).

Comment: @seven-phases-max I'm using 1.7.0 via [Koala](http://koala-app.com/). Seems rather old :D

Comment: Well, either way I guess you still can hack it by moving the comment to a separate css file and import-inline this file first :P.